# java BigDecimal arithmaticException invalid operation

Tags: java, bigdecimal, largenumber

I cant find why I got a  `java.lang.ArithmeticException: Invalid operation` while using big decimal.

```
public static String E (int exponent, String value){
BigDecimal ten= new BigDecimal("10");
BigDecimal tempValue=new BigDecimal (value);
return tempValue.multiply(ten.pow(exponent)).toString();
}
```

Some of the exponents have values such as `-27`. Is there any way around this since it would be difficult to store the original values with many zeros. I chose **BigDecimal** since I needed to precision.

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are raising things to negative exponents, you must specify a [`MathContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) in [`BigDecimal.pow(int, MathContext)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow%28int,%20java.math.MathContext%29) so it knows how much precision to use -- otherwise, `BigDecimal` will try to compute it to infinite precision, which is not possible for some values.

(Unless you can be *absolutely sure* that the operation you're doing has an exact result with a finite number of digits.)

Comment: i am absolutely sure that it doesnt have an infinite precision. I still get that error though. Using double will not reach as far while some operations performed tend to be done near 0. I dont see how 10 to the power off something can be an infinite precision and a scientific calculator can hold the value up to -99. Otherwise would there be a better way to represent this?

Comment: Could you give us the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @ErrorMessages `pow(int)` will, when given a negative number, throw a ArithmeticException. Always. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#pow%28int%29

Comment: Right.  I should've noticed that.  That said, @ErrorMessages, it looks like your method is actually equivalent to `scaleByPowerOfTen`, which might be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

To multiply a BigDecimal by a power of 10 it's probably clearer to the reader (and more efficient, too) to use [`movePointLeft`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointLeft%28int%29) and [`movePointRight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight%28int%29):

Instead of `tempValue.multiply(ten.pow(exponent))` you would use `tempValue.movePointRight(exponent)`.